# Boot issues on a EFI System

Tags: boot

I have tried installing ubuntu 13.04 (AMD64) on a new gateway PC alongside win8 as well as completely deleting all partitions and installing it as a standalone OS.  In all cases it will not boot.  I have changed the BIOS to legacy (turning off secure boot).  Ubuntu install but cannot be read at boot. Grub2 also appears during the install dialog. HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you convert to MBR instead of gpt. If still gpt you need a bios_grub partition. The run Boot-Repair.

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot.:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair